# gapi client urlshortener url shows undefined

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, onload

Iam getting this error

> "https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/urlshortener/v1.0/rest?fields=kind%2Cname%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods%2CbatchPath%2Cid&pp=0&key={my-api}
>   404" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var longUrl = 'any long url';
        function makeShort() {
            var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
                'resource': {
                    'longUrl': longUrl // Your long URL
                }
            });
            request.execute(function(response) 
            {
                console.log("Short URL:"+ response.id);
            });
        }

        function googleLoad() {
            // Insert your browser API key generated from Google Developer Console
            gapi.client.setApiKey({my-api}); 
            gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});

        }
        window.onload = googleLoad;     
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>

    <body>
        <button onclick="makeShort();">Create short URL</button> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Google Developers blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html):

> [...]
>   until March 30, 2019, when we will discontinue the APIs.

The API essentially has been discontinued since March 30, 2019, so it is not usable anymore.

#### Alternatives

- As suggested by Google in the blog post, you can use [Firebase's Dynamic Links API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links).
- Otherwise, you may be interested in checking out other URL shorting services such as [bit.ly](https://dev.bitly.com/) or [ow.ly](https://developer.hootsuite.com/docs/api-overview)